# Zigzag Border CSS - Display issues in FireFox and Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, display

I am adding a simple zigzag border to a div and have noticed some weird display issues on Chrome and Firefox. Most noticeable on FireFox.

Here's my code:

```
section#interview:after {
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #FF7171 16px, transparent 0),linear-gradient(45deg, #FF7171 16px, transparent 0);
    background-position: left-bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 32px 32px;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -26px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
}
```

I have also setup a basic fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/3fyn2a6q/1/

When viewing the fiddle in FireFox I see a faint grey outline around the zigzag (see image below). This is not visible on Chrome.

Firefox: 
[image]

On Chrome I have different issue. When resizing the browser window I see a faint red line above the border. If I adjust the `top` by either `1px` up or down the line goes. If I adjust it a bit more it appears again. I just don't get it. See image below:

Chrome:

[image]

Am I missing something in my css? I really don't want to resort to using a repeating image instead of pure css (it's 2017!).

Comment: Sounds a lot like an anti-aliasing issue.

Comment: @Paulie_D not something I know much about. Is it possible to resolve?

Comment: Not sure, each browser tends to do it a different way as you have experienced.

Comment: 3 yrs later I'm just facing this exact problem. It's ok on Chrome desktop but not on my android phone and even shows up in Chrome's devtools using mobile view. If someone has a solution please share!